# Free CDN - content delivery network (specifically for hosting jQuery)

Tags: jquery, hosting, external, cdn

Does anyone know of a good/free CDN?  We're hosting a small web app and want to load the Jquery JavaScripts from a CDN.  Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Both [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) and [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/) offer the latest jQuery from their distribution networks.  Included links go to the pages listing all of the resources available from the respective CDNs.

Answer (score 8):

With the Google CDN you **can** use the latest version of JQuery

For instance, if you want the lastest 1.X.X, the 1.4.X otherwise the specific 1.4.2 version just link your page to one of those:

```
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
```

Same thing with the [other hosted javascript libs](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#AjaxLibraries).

Comment: An Example of script linking:

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

If its just the jQuery API you want to host then you could use either Google or Microsoft CDN's as they both host the js files for this API

Microsoft : http://www.asp.net/ajax/CDN/

Google : http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses.  We took a quick look at the Google Hosting (before posting here), and were initially very excited.

On closer inspection, we were a bit disappointed that they did not have a way to link to the latest update of Jquery - basically you link to a version, and if there is a newer version, you then have to manually update all your links to the newest one.

But still, it solves the problem for us, so thanks.

Comment: Isn't that a *good* thing? Automatically updating jquery might break your site :/